Sturm Liouville Problem $y''+\lambda y=0, y(0)=0, y(\pi)-y'(\pi)=0.$
The question is about finding eigenvalues and eigenfunction of the problem Sturm Liouville problem $$y''+\lambda y=0, y(0)=0, y(\pi)-y'(\pi)=0.$$
I can solve two cases when $\lambda =0$ and $\lambda >0.$ But there is some problem when solving the differential equation for $\lambda <0.$
Case 3: $\lambda < 0$
Let $\lambda = -\nu^2$ with $\nu > 0$. The equation becomes:
$$
y'' - \nu^2 y = 0.
$$
The general solution is:
$$
y(x) = C_1 e^{\nu x} + C_2 e^{-\nu x}.
$$
Applying the boundary conditions:
$$
y(0) = 0 \implies C_1 + C_2 = 0 \implies C_2 = -C_1.$$
Thus:
$$
y(x) = C_1 \left( e^{\nu x} - e^{-\nu x} \right) = C_1 \sinh(\nu x).
$$
From the second boundary condition:
$$
y(\pi) - y'(\pi) = 0 \implies C_1 \sinh(\nu \pi) - C_1 \nu \cosh(\nu \pi) = 0.
$$
Factor out $C_1$ (which is non-zero for non-trivial solutions):
$$
\sinh(\nu \pi) - \nu \cosh(\nu \pi) = 0.
$$
Now how to show that last equation has no solution? Please help. Thank you.

It seems that there is a solution $\nu \approx \pm 0.996$, see wolfram alpha.

@tkw but I need hand calculation only .

There is no way to solve this equation by hand.

@xpaul is an exercise of S.L. Ross's book of differential equations. It is not mentioned that it is a computer exercise.
